# Text processing with two files

Tags: python, text, awk

I have two text files in the following format:

The first is this on every line:

`Key1:Value1`

The second is this:

`Key2:Value2`

Is there a way I can replace `Value1` in `file1` by the `Value2` obtained from using it as a key in `file2`?

For example:

file1:

```
foo:hello
bar:world
```

file2:

```
hello:adam
bar:eve
```

I would like to get:

```
foo:adam
bar:eve
```

There isn't necessarily a match between the two files on every line. Can this be done neatly in awk or something, or should I do it naively in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two dictionaries, one for each file. For example:

```
file1 = {}
for line in open('file1', 'r'):
    k, v = line.strip().split(':')
    file1[k] = v
```

Or if you prefer a one-liner:

```
file1 = dict(l.strip().split(':') for l in open('file1', 'r'))
```

Then you could do something like:

```
result = {}
for key, value in file1.iteritems():
    if value in file2:
        result[key] = file2[value]
```

Another way is you could generate the key-value pairs in reverse for file1 and use sets. For example, if your file1 contains `foo:bar`, your file1 dict is `{bar: foo}`.

```
for key in set(file1) & set(file2):
    result[file1[key]] = file2[key]
```

Basically, you can quickly find common elements using set intersection, so those elements are guaranteed to be in file2 and you don't waste time checking for their existence.

**Edit:** As pointed out by @pepr You can use `collections.OrderedDict` for the first method if order is important to you.

Comment: Possibly the `collections.OrderedDict` (Python 2.7+ and 3.1+) could be an option to write the values back to the file in the original order (if it is to be written back). [I do not like the **fileX** name given to a dictionary.  Also, an open file should always be closed earlier than by runtime.]

Answer (score 2):

The awk solution:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {FS = OFS = ":"}
  NR==FNR {val[$1] = $2; next}
  $1 in val {$2 = val[$1]}
  {print}
}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
join -t : -1 2 -2 1 -o 0 2.2 -a 2 <(sort -k 2 -t : file1) <(sort file2)
```

The input files must be sorted on the field they are joined on.

The options:

- `-t :` - Use a colon as the delimiter
- `-1 2` - Join on field 2 of file 1
- `-2 1` - Join on field 1 of file 2
- `-o 0 2.2` - Output the join field followed by field 2 from file2 (separated by the delimiter character)
- `-a 2` - Output unjoined lines from file2

Answer (score 0):

Once you have:

```
file1 = {'foo':'hello', 'bar':'world'}
file2 = {'hello':'adam', 'bar':'eve'}
```

You can do an ugly one liner:

```
print dict([(i,file2[i]) if i in file2 else (i,file2[j]) if j in file2 else (i,j) for i,j in file1.items()])
{'foo': 'adam', 'bar': 'eve'}
```

As in your example you are using both the `keys` and `values` of `file1` as `keys` in `file2`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not consider using basic Unix/Linux commands cheating, then here is a solution using paste and awk.

`paste file1.txt file2.txt | awk -F ":" '{ print $1":"$3 }'`

Comment: This solution assumes that keyed datum in `file1` is found on the same line number of that file as the line number in `file2` where the reference occurs. It's reasonable to assume that this is true just by coincidence a in the small sample data given.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (probably GNU sed):

```
sed 's#\([^:]*\):\(.*\)#/\\(^\1:\\|:\1$\\)/s/:.*/:\2/#' file2 | sed -f - file1
```

Answer (score 0):

TXR:

```
@(next "file2")
@(collect)
@key:@value1
@  (cases)
@    (next "file1")
@    (skip)
@value2:@key
@  (or)
@    (bind value2 key)
@  (end)
@  (output)
@value2:@value1
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr subst.txr
foo:adam
bar:eve
```